# Is there a way to Access Plugins from slick grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have plugged in Auto-column resize plugin into slikgrid and I m trying to find a way to access its methods outside the plug in.

```
$.extend(true, window, {
        "Slick": {
          "Plugins": {
              "AutoColumnSize": AutoColumnSize
          }
        }
      });
```

I have used this below code to plug this in.

```
var newGrid = new Slick.Grid($grid, dataView, this.columns, options);
newGrid.registerPlugin(new Slick.Plugins.AutoColumnSize());
```

Im trying to use grid.reSizeColumn(e) //method of AutoColumnSize plugin.

Can some one give me a pointer so I can do this??

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get to it.
Slick.Plugins is available throughout the app and from the plugin I am returning the method that I want to expose like::

```
return {
            init: init,
            destroy: destroy,
            reSizeColumn: reSizeColumn
        };
```

That gave me access to the method and now i am able to call it.
Thanks Folks.

Comment: Could you extend your answer? I'm trying to call the 'resizeAllColumns', I have adapted your code but now I don't know how to call it. I'm trying with: grid.registerPlugin( new Slick.AutoColumnSize()); grid.resizeAllColumns()